# Should I take Math GRE Subject Tests for applying to Philosophy Phd to study Philosophy of Math?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

If I was interested in studying philosophy of another field (e.g. philosophy of math or physics), would philosophy phd programs I apply to be interested to see my scores on the gre subject test for that field (e.g. gre math or physics subject test)?

Comment: I'm sure a good score wouldn't hurt you, but I don't know of any PhD program that requires one (I just checked Pitt. HPS and MIT). But I would think they'd be more impressed by course work or achievements in those fields than a GRE score for those fields. (My own research areas do not include philosophy of science, but I do have a BS in chemistry and did take the subject test for chemistry during my junior or senior year; I don't think that mattered by the time I applied to PhD programs in 2007 or so).

Comment: @Smithey, this question is now almost two years old, do you have an answer to this question yourself now?  I'm in a similar situation.

Comment: It occurs to me now that most philosophy professors probably wouldn't know how to evaluate a math gre subject test score.